# Splash screen not working with android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I have tried everything my config.xml code is this:

```
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000" />



  <platform name="android">

    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

</platform>
```

Please help someone

Answer (score 0):

In android you will need to write the code for splash screen in src/`<yourpackagefolder>`/`<yourprojectname>`.java file

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.screen);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",60000);
    }`

Where you need to add the splashscreen file name "screen.png" in res/rawable-land-hdpi & drawable-land-ldpi & drawable-land-mdpi & drawable-land-xhdpi & drawable-port-hdpi & drawable-port-ldpi & drawable-port-mdpi & drawable-port-xhdpi. As these are the different screen sizes.

Same way you can add the icons into drawable-`<resolution>` folders respectively